# NodeJS redirecting to Angular5 route, returns JSON, not page?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, passport.js

Im am trying to redirect a user after (in the API) it is detected the user is no longer logged in. 
For instance, the user starts an action (PUT) to the api, the api checks the user status, if logged in, the action is performed and data is returned. If not, the user needs to be redirected to the login-page, the loginroute (/login) is defined in the Angular5 router.

This works nice, if logged in, all is fine.

If not logged in, it is detected and Logged, but the redirect doesnt work, at first it tried to use PUT on /login resulting in 404, that doenst work so i added 303, now it GETs on /login. But... in my browser console i get...

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad ( etc
```

Somehow it seems it is trying to parse the page as JSON???
What is going on here? I hope someone can give me a hint so i can forward to this page if someone is not logged in :)

Some code (Using Angular 5)...

In node/express/passport there is a small bit of middleware to check status...

```
function isTeacher(req, res, next) {

    if (req.isAuthenticated() && (req.user.google.role=="teacher" || req.user.google.role=="admin") )

        return next();

    console.log("Not loggedin");    
    res.redirect(303, '/login');

};
```

In the router...

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'studentlists', component: ListselectorComponent},
    { path: 'studentlisteditor/:listid', component: StudentlisteditorComponent},
    { path: 'teacherlists', component: TeacherlistselectorComponent},
    { path: 'teacherlisteditor/:listid',
        component: TeacherlisteditorComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'results', component: TeacherresultsComponent },
            {path: 'edit', component: ListeditorComponent },
        ]
    },
    ];
```

(I am a real beginner so there probably are more weird things in my code... sorry for that, all input welcome ;)

Comment: You should handle redirection in the Angular app, not in the Node.js app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for you is to avoid the redirection in the backend and do it from the frontend, what I'll do: In your isTeacher method if the user is not allowed return a response indicating it's not valid and then in your Angular app use a route guard to check this answer and if it's not the expected then redirect to login. [Angular official docs about route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

Comment: So... Make API call -> Check status in NodeJS -> if not loggedin, return this info to Angular -> Let Angular redirect (preferably using route guards)  
That sounds like logic! Time to make some changes then... (that's what you get from not having a proper programming back-ground!) Thanx Niral and Talavera!

Comment: Exactly! Welcome ;)